# What is CAN PRO?

Tags: canada, hst, tax-credit, gst, gst-credit

I have had several deposits into my bank account over the past year from this ($125.??) I am sure it is federal and provincial and some kind of credit.  But for what?

Comment: What province do you live in?

Answer (score 2):

It's a credit from the provincial government.  It could be a for a bunch of different things, but it's essentially a tax rebate / refund.